# Mamp Os X.7 AIR application

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion, mamp

I create an AIR application with mysql connection.
On my computer Mac OS.6 all work well.

But on other computer (on Mac Os X.7) php file result doesn't work (print $dom->saveXML();)

```
      <?php

    require_once ('../MySQL.php');
    require_once ('../conf.php');

    if(isset($_POST['usrName']))      
    $user=$_POST['usrName'];
    if(isset($_POST['usrPwd']))      
    //$pwd=SHA1($_POST['usrPwd']);
    $pwd=($_POST['usrPwd']);
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER, DB_PWD);
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $link);

            $query = 'SELECT 12Praticien_02.prCode FROM 12Praticien_02'
                     .' WHERE 12Praticien_02.prCode = "' . $user . '"'
                     .' AND 12Praticien_02.prMotPasse = "' . $pwd . '"';


            //return    $mySql->query($query) ? true : false;


    $recordset = mysql_query($query, $link);

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $rootNode= $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('OrthoExpertDB'));


    while($row_recordset = mysql_fetch_array($recordset))
    {

        $record = new DomElement("c", "");
        $rootNode->appendChild($record);

        $record->SetAttribute("co", utf8_encode($row_recordset[0]));

    }
    mysql_free_result($recordset);
    mysql_close();


  $dom->save('debugxmlN.xml');
    print $dom->saveXML();

    ?>
```

Indeed this php file return no result  nether with save method and nether with saveXML.
I guess that this problem has a link with privilege and I apply 777 on htdocs but the result is the same : NOTHINGS.

So can you help me to solve that?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check the log files? like in the mamp log directory.

anyway a part from quick prototyping the best solution for web developing would be to configure the apache2 server that comes with osx. and stick to virtual-host(s) in order to recreate something that's closest as possible to the production environment.

that's my 2cent.

anyways, back to your problem, the quickest check you could perform is dig into the error_log
that should be placed into

```
 /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error_log
```

and last but not least, turn on the logging at runtime, it might help a little bit

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Comment: is it possible that the query you perform got no results? did you also check the paths? are ok? just try to touch a file in the beginning of the script to make sure that the file-writing process can be carried out with success

Comment: In my case, query has result. But script return no domdocument, neither with save method neither with print neither with echo.

Comment: I solve this problem with root activation and apply all permission with terminal. Thanks

Comment: so it was a Chmod -R 777 issue indeed. well I'm happy to know that u solved it :-)